# How to replace scrollbars of a div with overflow:auto with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a small div that will be used to scroll between pictures in a jquery image zoom plugin for an eCommerce website.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div style="width:125px;height:300px;overflow:auto;margin:auto;">
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:brown;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:purple;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2o482ofp/

I need to hide the scrolls bars and instead have fixed arrow buttons to move up and down within the div.
I am trying to mimic the functionality that can be found on https://www.daraz.pk/ca-sports-black-pu-running-shoes-for-men-6605753.html

I did a lot of googling but could not find any tutorial, guide, plugin or anything regarding what I am trying to do so if anyone can please help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var blockHeight = 75;
var marginTop = 10;

$('.up').click(function(){
    
    var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

  var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);
    
    console.log('currentOffset', currentOffset);
    var result = currentOffset - blockHeight - marginTop;

  $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
});

$('.down').click(function(){

     var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

  var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);
    var result = currentOffset + blockHeight + marginTop;
    
    console.log('.currentOffset', currentOffset)

  $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");

})
```

```css
div > div {
  
  transition: margin 1s ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="up">up</button>
<button class="down">down</button>
<div style="width:125px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;margin:auto;">
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:brown;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:purple;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</div>
```